# ListBox игнорирует обновление ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ModpacksGrid" Margin="0,40,200,0"
    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ModpacksListboxItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ForModpackList}">
</ListBox>
```

Код стиля приводить смысла нет, ибо он (сам ListBox) в принципе работает при запуске.

Данное окно привязано к своей VM, в ней реализована коллекция `public List<ModpacksGroup> ForModpackList => Config.LocalModpacks;`
Сама VM реализует `inotifypropertychanged` с помощью KindOfMagic (который везде работает в проекте).

Так-же класс Config, ModpacksGroup, и Modpack, входящие в данную структуру тоже реализуют `inotifypropertychanged`.

Однако при добавлении элемента в `Config.LocalModpacks` ListBox не обновляется. Обновляется `ForModpackList`, и даже если дебаггером залезть в свойства `ListBox'a`, то в них в ItemsSource можно найти добавленный элемент. Однако он не отображается. Почему?

Comment: так вы добавляете элемент в `List<ModpacksGroup>`, который не реазиует INPC, вам надо либо юзать `ObservableCollection`, либо самому руками вызывать событие обновления всего свойства `ForModpackList`. А то как ваш View догадается, что вы что то добавили в какой то список - кто его оповестит об этом?

Comment: Погуглить на счет KindOfMagic - он на этапе компиляции реализует inpc.

Comment: что никак не решает вашу проблему. Каким образом он реализует INPC для списка? - Никаким.

Comment: Тут не INPC нужен, а `INotifyCollectionChanged`, которого нету не в вашем Magic, не в List. Переделайте `public List<ModpacksGroup>` в `public ObservableCollection<ModpacksGroup>` (как вам сказали выше) и будет счастье.

Comment: Да. Сработало. Оформите как ответ. Но как-то странно, я множество раз до этого использовал List, и отдавал реализацию на INPC и KindOfMagic. Не знаю, как это работало, видимо на одной голой вере... Хотя, возможно если менять список из того-же класса, где он находится, то будет работать.

Comment: Если у вас **из кода** меняется значение свойства, то это свойство обязательно должно вызвать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Если у вас идут изменения коллекции (добавление/удаление) **из кода**, то эта коллекция обязана также вызывать `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Оба этих интерфейса оповещают привязанные в View контролы и те обновляют свои данные. Если у вас изменения идут с View части, то реализовывать интерфейсы не надо. По поводу ответа - где то был дубликат, позже может найду и подам на закрытие, дублировать ответ у меня как то желания нет)

Comment: *либо самому руками вызывать событие обновления всего свойства `ForModpackList`. А то как ваш View догадается, что вы что то добавили в какой то список - кто его оповестит об это* — вот это не поможет, кстати, WPF достаточно умен, чтобы увидеть, что ссылка фактически не изменилась и не станет перечитывать список и обновлять. Поэтому **только** INCC, либо вычисляемое свойство, которое при каждом запросе будет выдавать новую ссылку. @tym32167

Comment: @АндрейNOP ха, да, об этом я не подумал, подловили меня :)